# Insert html icon within a div with .before method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this case,
I have some div like:

```
  <div class="topImg">
   <div class="topImgIcon">
    <img src="img/bbbbb.png" class="topImgIcon"><span class="tittle">Chat Window</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And I want to insert this img link with one icon within this div. Is one X to close the windows but show some html code like `form`.

See my jQuery code:

```
var myDivImg = $( "<div class="topImg"></div>" )
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#maisinfo").before(myDivImg, '<a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>');

  $("#maisinfo").hide(); 

  $("#show").bind("click",function(){
    $("#maisinfo").slideToggle("slow");
      return false;
    });
});
```

I want to insert the `html: <a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>` within `.before()` inside the div topImg in my HTML. I try create the div inside `.before()` but, jQuery create other same div.

Someone can help me please and make some explanation for I understand what I did wrong?

Comment: Your code says that the two pieces of HTML will be inserted before `#maisinfo`.

Comment: [`myDivImg.before('<a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>');`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Comment: my Div #maisinfo element is to show the form if user click in my icon X (img src element). But I need put this X inside the #topImg div element.

Comment: Do you want the `<a>` inside the top DIV or before it? Use `.prepend()` to put it inside at the beginning.

Comment: `javascript:window.close()` probably won't work.  A script can only close a window that it opened with `window.open()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add something inside the DIV, you use `.prepend()` or `.append()`, depending on whether you want it at the beginning or end. `.before()` puts it outside the DIV, right before it.

```
$("#topDiv").prepend('<a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>');
```

Comment: thanks for  the explanation, but, I need put my X img src element inside the topImg. My jQuery code is for if user click in the X, will show one form

Comment: Then use `.prepend`, not `.before`.

Comment: I use your code and works fine, but my  div dont show when I click inside the X more. Do you know what the problem?

Comment: I don't see an X in the HTML, so I have no idea. Can you edit the question to add a stack snippet that contains all the necessary code?

Comment: There's no `<div id="maisinfo">` in the HTML you posted.

Comment: the X is inside the prepend <img src="img/close.png">

Comment: Why should clicking on that show a DIV? The only code you have there is `window.close()`

Comment: Where is `id="show"`? That's the button that shows the DIV.

Comment: I will open one new question

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the div with ".html('xxx')" or with .append/prepend('xxx').

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  var myDivImg = $( "<div class="topImg"></div>" );
  // or var myDivImg=$('.topImg'); // => if the element exists
  var myInsertDiv='<a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>';

  // first method
  myDivImg.html( myInsertDiv ); // replace all html in this div with the content from "myInsertDiv"

  //second method
  myDivImg.append( myInsertDiv );// add the html from "myInsertDiv" as last child in your "myDivImg"
  //or
  myDivImg.append( myInsertDiv );// add the html from "myInsertDiv" as first child in your "myDivImg"

});
```

EDIT:
to close your div use something like this

```
$('body').on('click','.imgclose',function(){
 $('.topImg').slideUp('slow');//close your parent-main div
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".topImg").append("<div id='maisinfo'></div>");
  $("#maisinfo").before('<a class="imgClose" href="javascript:window.close()"><img src="img/close.png"></a>');

  $("#maisinfo").hide(); 

  $("#show").bind("click",function(){
    $("#maisinfo").slideToggle("slow");
      return false;
    });
});
 </script>
  <div class="topImg">
   <div class="topImgIcon">
    <img src="img/bbbbb.png" class="topImgIcon"><span class="tittle">Chat Window</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```